# MySQL insert_id returning null even though there was an insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, auto-increment

I have the following PHP code.  I wish to return the last id of the insert:

```
$sql = $this->dbLink->prepare("
            INSERT INTO VesselTransits (CreatedByUserID, TerminalID, VesselArrivalDate, VesselNameID)
            VALUES (?,?,?,?)
    ");
//i=integer, s=string
$sql->bind_param('iisi', $userID, $terminalID, $arrivalDate, $vesselNameID);
$userID          = $this->invoiceData['userID'];
$terminalID      = $this->invoiceData['terminalID'];
$arrivalDate     = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->invoiceData['berthDate']));
$vesselNameID    = $this->invoiceData['vesselNameID'];
$sql->execute();
$vesselTransitID = $sql->insert_id;
//echo('RecordInvoice line '.__LINE__.'<pre>');print_r($vesselTransitID);echo('</pre>');exit();

return($vesselTransitID);
```

My DB schema is as follows:

```
CreatedByUserID   int
CreationDate      datetime
ModifiedByUser    int
ModifyDate        datetime
TerminalID        int
VesselArrivalDate datetime
VesselNameID      int
VesselTransitID   int [auto_increment]
```

I've thrown the kitchen sink at it, but no dice. No matter what I do, `$vesselTransitID` is always undefined. I have verified that there is actually an insert.  I'm left with the only (HORRIBLE) option of running another select and returning the MAX VesselTransitID, which doesn't guarantee the correct result.

Comment: Try `$this->dbLink->insert_id;` it is a property of the mysqli class (the connection) not the statement class

Comment: Are you using mysqli or are you using some other library that uses mysqli internally? `insert_id` can never be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the statement object has a `insert_id` property, it does appear to cause issues from time to time, as here.

As the statement objects `insert_id` property is still after all these years not completely documented, I would suggest for simplicity and safety using the connection objects version of `insert_id`

So do

```
$vesselTransitID = $this->dbLink->insert_id;
```

Comment: That's not true. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php

Comment: @Dharman Strictly you are right, **but** using the statement objects version has caused issues in the past as documented in the manual, it is **still** also not completely documented in the manual, Therefore I would always suggest using the connection mysqli objects version. It does appear to have caused this OP an issue to emphasis the potential for problems